# How to solve "Invalid character found in the HTTP protocol [HTTP/1.10x0aHost:]"?

Tags: java, html, spring-boot, tomcat

After I deployed my SpringBoot project to an AWS EC2 instance, an exception shows up frequently:

```
2020-07-31 01:56:21.487 DEBUG 7340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase    : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@3d89313d:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@11d95ea0:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/172.31.38.151:8080 remote=/198.98.61.139:33842]], Read from buffer: [0]
2020-07-31 01:56:21.487 DEBUG 7340 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@3d89313d:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@11d95ea0:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/172.31.38.151:8080 remote=/198.98.61.139:33842]], Read direct from socket: [175]

2020-07-31 01:56:21.487  INFO 28770 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the HTTP protocol [HTTP/1.10x0aHost:]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:560) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:260) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.36.jar!/:9.0.36]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

It doesn't break the project, and every functionality is running fine.
But I don't know if it will cause some problems in the future, so I would like to solve it now.

Could anyone give me some hints about what causes this exception please?

Comment: `0x0a` is a newline character if that's helpful

Comment: are you sending SSL traffic to apache and apache is not configured with a private SSL certificate to decrypt it ?

Comment: @ArunK Actually, I don't quite understand what you said since I am very junior. This project is a restful api for sending email. The exception doesn't occur when the api receives a request. Instead, it occurs when there is no request "manually" sent. I have added 2 more lines to the code. Hope that helps explain the issue. So, to answer you question, I don't know whether the requests I send are SSL traffic, but even if they are, they don't cause the exception.

Comment: Well, what @doublesharp provided is a start. It looks like the system is not properly interpreting the newline character or it wasn't sent in properly. With HTTP header, you usually have something like

`HTTP/1.1`
`Host: www.google.com`

Something like that. It's complaining that, instead of encountering a new line character, it's literally getting `0x0a`, I think. Excuse the editing, I can't figure out how to insert a line break in this comment box. There's supposed to be a line break after the `HTTP/1.1`

Comment: Please take a look at my reply to ArunK. Is that possible that there are some requests sent to this EC2 instance automatically? The exception is not caused by the requests sent by me. I don't know where is this new line char... I am sure no one else is sending requests. @DavidTran

Comment: Is this project publicly accessible now that it's on EC2? Are you getting this error log entry frequently, but everything still functions fine? If both are true, is it possible that you're just getting queries from people snooping around? I get those on my web server sometimes. They'll send in bad requests to try to look for vulnerabilities in the system and it triggers errors in my logs. Are you able to track those errors back to an IP that triggered the bad request?

Comment: @DavidTran Your point 1 is true, 2 is also true but not very frequently, maybe every hour. I am trying to track the errors. Thank you so much for your hints!

Comment: @powerseed unless this is you, this person is having the same issue https://github.com/FusionAuth/fusionauth-issues/issues/635

Comment: @powerseed what OS are you running? Is this a Windows server? My guess is that the newline expected by the server is different than is what is being sent by the client. https://github.com/selakavon/spring-rest-oauth2-mongo/issues/5

Comment: @doublesharp Thx for the info, but that person doesn't have a solution either. And, the problem is, who sent that problematic request? I didn't. Please take a look at the code, I just added the IP address of the sender to the code. It is not me. I think David Tran could be right. It is just some people snooping around.

Comment: @DavidTran I just checked the IP address of sender of the problematic request, and it was not me. The first 2 lines of code show the IP. I think you are right, this exception is caused by queries from people snooping around. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found it related to a change to Tomcat 8.5 introduced in version 8.5.44. The description on this is `Fix: 63578: Improve handling of invalid requests so that 400 responses are returned to the client rather than 500 responses. (markt)`  (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/changelog.html#Tomcat_8.5.44_(markt))

In that situation some legacy code making a manual request being made to an HTTP GET endpoint was sending something like:

`"GET " + path + " HTTP/1.1\n"`

This needed to be changed to:

`"GET " + path + " HTTP/1.1\r\n"` to fix the problem.

Putting details here for future reference to others with the same issue. Tomcat would have fixed this to be more compliant, that might break legacy code that was not doing the right thing.